# Graph library implementation

Tags: graph, implementation

I' m trying to implement a weighted graph. I know that there are two ways to implement a weighted graph. Either with a two dimensional array(adjacency matrix) or with an array of linked lists(adjacency list). Which one of the two is more efficient and faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which one of the two is more efficient and faster?

That depends on your usage and the kinds of graphs you want to store.

Let n be the number of nodes and m be the number of edges. If you want to know whether two nodes u and v are connected (and the weight of the edge), an adjacency matrix allows you to determine this in constant time (in [O-notation](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/), O(1)), simply by retrieving the entry `A[u,v]`. With an adjacency list, you will have to look at every entry in u's list, or v's list - in the worst case, there could be n entries. So edge lookup for an adjacency list is in O(n).

The main downside of an adjacency matrix is the memory required. Alltogether, you need to store n^2 entries. With an adjacency list, you need to store only the edges that actually exist (m entries, asuming a directed graph). So if your graph is sparse, adjacency lists clearly occupy much less memory.

My conclusion would be: Use an adjacency matrix if your main operation is retrieving the edge weight for two specific nodes; under the condition that your graphs are small enough so that n^2 entries fit in memory. Otherwise, use the adjacency list.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd go for the linked lists approach, assuming that it will often be a sparse graph (i.e. most of the array cells are a waste of space).

Went to wikipedia to read up on [adjacency lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) (been ages since I used graphs) and it has a nice section on the trade-offs between the 2 approaches. Ultimately, as with many either/or choices it will come down to 'it depends', based on what are the likely use cases for your library.

After reading the wiki article, I think another point in favor of using lists would be attaching data to each directed segment (or even different weights, think of walk/bike/car distance between 2 points etc.)